# How can we collect code coverage report from a file with "es" extension in jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, code-coverage, babel-jest

I am trying to collect code coverage from the file with the "es" extension(i.e. sum.es) (here **es** means **ECMA script**).

This is what folder structure looks like

[image: folder structure]

I'm able to run both test files (`sum.test.js`, `sum.test.es`)

[image: output]

but unable to generate code coverage for the `sum.es` file.

jest.config.js file:

[image: jest config file]

Can anyone help?

Comment: After you run this, can you please show what you have inside the `coverage` folder?

Comment: why using image is discouraged: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @DmytroHolysh I have updated the image of the folder structure, it contains coverage as well.

Comment: could you please share link to some git repo where you can reproduce this? It would be easier to check what's wrong in this case

Comment: https://github.com/deep1358/code-coverage-jest

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot about this question, and finally came to know that using
`"coverageProvider":"v8"` in jest.config.js file will solve this issue.

Comment: did you try adding `"coverageProvider":"v8"` to the jest config?